# Reading partitioned Avro files in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a bucket which has lots of data in Avro partitioned in a "hive" style, for example

```
s3://my-bucket/year=2018/month=03/day=25/file-name.avro
```

I am trying to access this data in Glue as:

```
val predicate = "year=2018 and month=03"
val opts = JsonOptions("""{ "paths": ["s3://my-bucket/"], "recurse": true }""")
val src = glueContext.getSource(connectionType = "s3"
                               , connectionOptions = opts
                               , pushDownPredicate = predicate
                               ).withFormat("avro")
```

But this expression fails with an exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.NonFatalException: User's pushdown predicate: year=2018 and month=03 can not be resolved against partition columns: []
```

I have tried something like this:

```
val predicate = "year=2018 and month=3"
val opts = JsonOptions("""{ "paths": ["s3://my-bucket/"], "recurse": true }""")
val src = glueContext.getSourceWithFormat(connectionType = "s3", format="avro", options = opts, pushDownPredicate = predicate)
```

but it wouldn't accept a pushdown predicate at all:

```
error: unknown parameter name: pushDownPredicate
```

I have also tried to add

```
"partitionKeys": ["year", "month", "day"]
```

to `JsonOptions`, also unsuccessfully.

How do I read hive-partitioned Avro serialised data in Glue without having a crawler?

Comment: Can you share your glue catalog table schema? Does it have partition columns defined correctly? You can create a table manually in Glue catalog and specify the serde to be used. You can do using Athena as well and in Athena query, you need to specify your partition columns.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to use pushdown predicate in `getSource()` and `getSourceWithFormat()` since internally it validates if fields in expression are actually partitions. In `getCatalogSource()` it loads this information from Glue Catalog and passes to validator. For `getSource()` and `getSourceWithFormat()` there is no possibility to pass custom list of data partitions to be used for validation and therefore it's not possible to use pushdown predicate.

As a workaround you can generate paths which include data partitions and pass it in `getSourceWithFormat()` through `options`. For example, if you want to load data for `year=2018 and (month=03 or month=04)` then your code should look like this:

```
val paths = Array(
    "s3://bucket/data/year=2018/month=03",
    "s3://bucket/data/year=2018/month=04"
)

val source = glueContext.getSourceWithFormat(
  connectionType = "s3",
  format = "avro",
  options = JsonOptions(Map(
    "paths" -> paths,
    "recurse": true
))).getDynamicFrame()
```

Please note that `source` DynamicFrame won't contain partition columns `year` and `month` so you might want to add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Best option, you have is to run crawler over `my_bucket` and then use

> glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
>       database = "my_S3_data_set",
>       table_name = "catalog_data_table",
>       push_down_predicate = predicate)